# Inconsistent Triad Conjecture

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Some context for this. We're developing an algorithm for estimation contests. Basically, you are given a question like how much (in dollars) is a ton of pennies worth, and you give an interval for your guess (the lower the better). So you have a scoring system $S (l, u, x)$ that takes your upper bound $u$ and lower bound $l$, and compares them to the true value $x$ in some way. We have three algorithms that do this. For any interval $(l, u)$, we denote the center of that interval by $\hat x$, and its score, with respect to true value $x$ is given by

$$S_1(l, u, x) = c(\log |x - \hat x| + \log |x - l| + \log |x - u|),$$
$$S_2(l, u, x) = c(\log(|1 - \frac{\hat x}{x}| + 1) + \log(|1 - \frac{l}{x}| + 1) + \log(|1 - \frac{u}{x}| + 1)), \text{ or}$$
$$S_3(l, u, x) = c(|\log(x) - \log(\hat x)| + |\log(x) - \log (l + \epsilon_{\text{mach}})| + |\log(x) - \log(u)|),$$
where $c$ is a constant that we use to manipulate the range of scores, and $\epsilon_{\text{mach}}$ is just a small number so we can handle a lower bound of 0 (and we're assuming everything else is greater than 0).

We also have three properties that we want in our algorithm. (1) It has to be scale-invariant, i.e., $S(\lambda x, \lambda l, \lambda u) = S(x, l, u)$. So if everything goes up an order of magnitude, the algorithm should give the same score. (2) It has to be "mirror" invariant. That is, if $u > l > x$, $S(x, 2x - u, 2x - l) = S(x, l, u)$, so an interval to the right of the true value should perform the same under an algorithm with an interval to the left of the true value. (3) It has to be sensitive to large numbers. For instance, we should clearly see $S(3\times 10^{13}, 50, 60) > S(3\times 10^{12}, 50, 60) > S(3\times 10^{11}, 50, 60) > S(3\times 10^{10}, 50, 60)$. So if your initial guess is way smaller than the true value, and you go up by an order of magnitude, your score should be able to reflect that.

Here is the interesting thing. All the algorithms we came up with can only satisfy at most 2 properties at a time. $S_1$ is mirror invariant and sensitive to large numbers, but not scale invariant. $S_2$ is scale invariant and mirror invariant, but not sensitive to large numbers. $S_3$ is scale-invariant and sensitive to large numbers, but not mirror invariant. That makes me wonder if there's something about those three properties that makes it break one of them if you have two of them. I'm trying to prove the inconsistent triad using proof by contradiction, but I can't go any further than writing down the hypotheses. Is this true?